# File Operation like create and delete restrict from groovy with SecureASTCustomizer

Tags: groovy

I have looking to restrict file operation like create file, delete file etc.
I have already check with **SecureASTCustomizer**  but it is only restrict from import package level. if any one direct use within groovy class without import package  so it is allow the script
and allow do operation this is the issue we faced.
I have try this but not success for the same.

```
MethodCallExpression methodCall = new MethodCallExpression(new VariableExpression("file"), "delete", MethodCallExpression.NO_ARGUMENTS);
           List l= new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(methodCall);
           secure.setExpressionsBlacklist(l);
```

can it possible to restrict only few method of particular class like delete method of File, new file creation etc.?
Please suggest any way to achieve this with groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't forbid calls to certain classes as far as I know, but you can globally replace the calls to certain methods use Groovy metaClass.

For example, before evaluating any scripts you might have, you can add this snippet to its text:

```
File.metaClass.delete = {
    println "We ain't deleting no files!"
    return false
}
```

When some Groovy code calls `File#delete()`, it will run this lambda instead of the actual method.

Example:

```
final shell = new GroovyShell()

final result = shell.evaluate '''
// our "protection"
File.metaClass.delete = {
    println "We ain't deleting no files!"
}

// the actual script
def f = new File('hello.txt')
def deleted = f.delete()
if (deleted) 'DELETED THE FILE!!'
else "File exists? ${f.isFile()}"
'''

println result
```

Running this prints this (assuming `hello.txt` exists in the working dir):

```
We ain't deleting no files!
File exists? true
```

This is good enough for DSLs but it's easily bypassable though.

Example of bypass:

```
File.metaClass.delete = {
    println "We ain't deleting no files!"
}

// malicious scripts
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
class NonGroovy {
    static deleteFile(File f) {
        f.delete()
    }
}
def f = new File('hello.txt')
def deleted = NonGroovy.deleteFile(f)
if (deleted) 'DELETED THE FILE!!'
else "File exists? ${f.isFile()}"
```

This prints:

```
DELETED THE FILE!!
```

There are more bypasses than you can probably defend against!

If this is for security purposes, I recommend actually using Java's `SecurityManager` and carefully setting policies for your scripts, or telling the Groovy compiler to use your own `ClassLoader` implementation that loads only classes that are safe to use (can be very difficult to do as well, but together with the restrictions you can set on the `SecureASTCustomizer` it may be manageable).

Also check this blog post: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/secure-groovy-script-execution-in-a-sandbox-ea39f80ee87

And this GitHub project it mentions that attempts to implement a secure sandbox in the context of Jenkins CI: https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-sandbox

Comment: HI, I have try with **SecureASTCustomizer** class but it is block as class level.i have try this `List<Class<? extends Expression>> expressionBlacklist = new ArrayList<>();
expressionBlacklist.add(org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.class);
secure.setExpressionsBlacklist(expressionBlacklist)`   but it is block all method call. can you suggest how i can block perticuler method of class.

Comment: You need to read the articles I linked. You can't do what you want because Groovy is a dynamic language and method calls can be invoked in multiple ways including reflection, so you just cannot do it in secure way.